# Conditional Calculating Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, pivot

I have the following table called `Invoice` table in SQL.

```
InvNo   Date     CustName   TypeOfSale  Tax        Grand
21      2019     AA         T1          $1.00      $10.00
22      2019     AA         T2          $2.00      $20.00
23      2019     BB         T1          $1.00      $10.00
24      2020     AA         T1          $1.00      $10.00
25      2020     BB         T1          $1.00      $10.00
26      2020     BB         T2          $2.00      $20.00
```

I'm trying to do a query that shows the following table
In the reselut I'm looking for revenue by year and also type of sale
If I assume `Revenue = Grand - Tax`  then:

```
CustName    Revenue TypeT1 2019     Revenue TypeT2 2019    Revenue TypeT1 2020      Revenue TypeT2 2020
AA          $9.00                   $18.00                 $9.00                    $0.00
BB          $9.00                   $0.00                  $9.00                    $18.00
```

I really appriciated for any help

Answer (score 2):

For a fixed list of types of sales and years, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select custname,
    sum(case when date = 2019 and typeofsale = 'T1' then grand - tax else 0 end) t1_2019,
    sum(case when date = 2019 and typeofsale = 'T2' then grand - tax else 0 end) t2_2019,
    sum(case when date = 2020 and typeofsale = 'T1' then grand - tax else 0 end) t1_2020,
    sum(case when date = 2020 and typeofsale = 'T2' then grand - tax else 0 end) t2_2020
from mytable
group by custname
```